# why is mission_control-jobs erroring with load path error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, solid-queue, mission-control-jobs

I have been attempting to set-up mission_control-jobs to a rails 7 app using SolidQueue, but I keep running in to the following error when accessing http://localhost:3000/jobs

```
Propshaft::MissingAssetError at /
The asset 'mission_control/jobs/application.css' was not found in the load path.
```

The set-up is quite simple:  add the gem, bundle, and add the route engine.  Running rake assets:reveal includes:

- mission_control/jobs/application.css
- mission_control/jobs/forms.css
- mission_control/jobs/jobs.css
- and, various mission_control js files

As you can see, "mission_control/jobs/application.css" is a seen asset.  Then, why am I be getting a PropShaft error that the file is not in the load path?

Answer (score 0):

Running rails assets:clobber seemed to fix the issue.